# MYSQL/PHP: Query with multiple joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get the following query to return the right information but it is returning different number of values for fields from the same table.

My data schema is 3 table:

```
airlines
id|descript|userid

travelers
id|airid|ftrav|ltrav|active

travair
id|travid|airid
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT a.id as `aid`,a.descript,userid,
  group_concat(t.id) as `tids`,
  group_concat(t.ftrav) as `ftravs`,
  group_concat(IFNULL(t.ltrav,'')) as `ltravs`, 
  group_concat(t.active) as `tactives`,  
  ta.airid 
  FROM airlines `a`
  LEFT JOIN travair `ta` 
    ON a.id = ta.airid
  LEFT JOIN travelers `t`
    ON ta.travid = t.id 
  WHERE a.userid='$userid' 
  GROUP BY a.id
```

Basically, I am trying to query the airlines table to get airlines but also pull the travelers for each of the airlines by way of the ta table which joins the two.

However, the group_concat fields all have different numbers of values in them.  In the actual table, I have largely eliminated missing values so that would not account for the differences in number of elements.  There seems to be something wrong with query.

Can anyone spot my error?  Have been struggling with this for a couple days.

Comment: need to see some data to work this out

Comment: What is your use case for such concatenation?  It's not like you are doing any real aggregation here, and you would still need to explode apart the resulting strings value in the application to be able to work with individual values.  Why not just read out full record set and aggregate within the application into appropriate data structure?

Comment: In the actual data for one particular airline, I am getting 57 travelerids but only 33 ftrav values.  As far as I know all of these traverlerids are associated with ftrav and ltrav values.  I have been trying to parse these one by one to figure out what is going awry but there are thousands of travelers and many airlines.

Comment: Use case is a web service that outputs JSON to an app.  The values for teach traveler need to be reassembled into a traveler object but I need to do this for multiple airlines, hence storing the traveler values in comma delimited strings.  I basically need a way to keep track of all the values for the traveler but orthogonal to returning the airlines.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Query looks ok to me. The only problem I can think of (beside some wrong assumptions) is `group_concat_max_len` value that is truncating some results - don't know what ftrav values are, but if 33 of them exceed (default) 1024 bytes then this might be an issue. Note that text chars might take more than one byte.

Comment: Shudder, I think you may be right but what is the syntax or command in PHP to set this.  I tried SET @@group_concat_max_len = 10000000; and also SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = value_numeric; immediately before  $sql = "SELECT..." and it does not run.

Comment: Shudder was correct.  This was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the problem with aggregation and joins is that the joins produce Cartesian products for matching keys.  In English, this means that you are joining along multiple dimensions and getting all combinations of different items for the same user.

What can you do?  The quick-and-dirty solution is to use the `distinct` keyword:

```
SELECT a.id as `aid`,a.descript,userid,
       group_concat(distinct t.id) as `tids`,
       group_concat(distinct t.ftrav) as `ftravs`,
       group_concat(distinct coalesce(t.ltrav, '')) as `ltravs`, 
       group_concat(distinct t.active) as `tactives`
```

A more scalable solution is to pre-aggregate each dimension to get the list along each dimension.

Note:  It is possible that `distinct` will not work in your case, if you happen to want all lists to be the same length.

Comment: I do want the lists to be the same length or equal to the number of travelers for each airline retrieved in the query .  The reason is that the results are being sent out via an API and on the other end, I need to reassemble the values for the traveler into records and for that I hope to use the index of each element in the list to put the fields back together into the full record.

Comment: How would I pre-aggregate?  Is that running a separate query?

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP_CONCAT`, like most aggregation functions, ignores NULL values. Since you are using left joins, any `GROUP_CONCAT`s on fields from tables on the right side of those joins may have null values for some of the pre-aggregation result rows.

Edit: If you want to synthesize "results" for the lacking data, you can aggregate calculated values instead; you've actually already done so once with this bit...

```
group_concat(IFNULL(t.ltrav,'')) as `ltravs`
```

.... you can just take it a bit further (make the lack of that data a bit more obvious) with something like this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(theField, '[Not Recorded]')) AS theList
```

Comment: Can you suggest a way to get lists for each of the traveler fields that are complete (i.e. have an element--blank if necessary--for each traveler)?